# How can I style the default Head tag in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I just created a basic page with `create-next-app` and am attempting to style the `index.js` page. While doing so, I added a `<nav></nav>` bar in the header and I am attempting to style it.

I'm wondering if there is a way to style the custom [`Head`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) tag in Next.js. I was hoping style the tag in the following manner:

in `Index.js`

```
<Head>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> A line </li>
      <li> Another line </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <title>A title</title>
</Head>
```

and then in `globals.css` do something like

```
Head {
  color: red;  
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure how I might apply a selector to the `Head` component and it's children and if it even makes sense to do so.
I realise that the question might not make sense so I seek your understanding if this sounds overly naive.

Would appreciate any guidance I can get.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`head` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) contains *metadata* like the title (which appears in the tab on the browser), links to stylesheets, and information about how small high-resolution decides (like phones) should render the page (i.e. if it is designed to adapt to them of if they should zoom out and show a desktop view).

It isn't allowed to contain *content* like `nav` or `ul`.

They have to be descendants of the `body` element.

Move your `nav` element to where it belongs and the need to style the `head` element goes away.

Answer (score 2):

The `<Head />` Next.js element is used to append tags to the head of the document. As such, it doesn't really make sense to add any visible html elements. It's basically just used for metadata, and for loading other scripts/external files.

You can read more about the Next.js `Head` element here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head

And you can read more about the html `head` element here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head